# SalesForce: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided does not match the recipient window's origin

Tags: salesforce

I have two accounts, from one account i created the app(Account 1) and in the second, i installed the managed app. In my primary account(Account 1), i am able to run the app but in all other accounts where i installed the app, i am getting this error: `Failed to execute ‘postMessage’ on ‘DOMWindow’: The target origin provided (‘https://na34.salesforce.com’) does not match the recipient window’s origin (‘https://esisf.na34.visual.force.com’).`

I know both of those url are different but i don't know how to make them same or fix this issue.

Please if anyone has any idea, please let me know how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a CORS issue.  You're also using the MyDomain feature, so there's a "esisf" subdomain before the na34 server subdomain.
Try whitelisting both urls in your CORS setup
[Use CORS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/extend_code_cors.htm)

Comment: Can you confirm if LockerService is on in both orgs?

Comment: It is not a Lighting app. It is a visual page, apex app. I am using version 38.0. So, i think locker service is not running.